# How to solve the error for using firestore package

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have faced with this problem, I need some help. And I already have used from these packages in **.yaml** file. `firebase_auth`, `firebase_storage`, `cloud_firestore` is my libs in the app. And I well use from location package in future.

```
get:
firebase_auth:
firebase_storage:
cloud_firestore:
```

**The Erorr**

```
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firestore.dart:112:15: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
        Error.throwWithStackTrace(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:11: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
    Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:17:9: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
  Error.throwWithStackTrace(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:12:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      ^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:11: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
    Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:17:9: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
  Error.throwWithStackTrace(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:12:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      ^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage_platform_interface-4.1.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:19:11: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
    Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage_platform_interface-4.1.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:22:9: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
  Error.throwWithStackTrace(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage_platform_interface-4.1.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(
      ^
```

Answer (score 0):

In .yaml file,use

```
    firebase_auth: use latest version
    firebase_storage:use latest version
    cloud_firestore:use latest version
```

from pub.dev

- https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth
- https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage
- https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

And after that run  `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`